# Firebase annonymous login exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I want to store images in firebase storage but when I try to upload image it gives below exception

> error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token

To solve this I tried doing anonymous login using the below method.

```
private void signInAnonymously() {
    mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            Log.d("onStart ",currentUser.getUid());


            // do your stuff
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authorisation successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    Log.e("url", "signInAnonymously:FAILURE", exception);
                }
            });
}
```

This gives below exception.

> signInAnonymously:FAILURE
>       com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred.
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdr.zzb(Unknown Source:38)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeu.zza(Unknown Source:16)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzc(Unknown Source:33)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.onFailure(Unknown Source:49)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:18)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)

I have added all the required dependencies and have also properly initialized firebase auth but it still keeps giving this error.

I have also enabled anonymous login in firebase console but issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your `google-services.json` file after enabling `anonymous login` in firebase console. If not download the new `google-services.json` file from firebase console. Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: I think the issue was due to the package name. I got this project from a friend and I created the firebase project myself too while I think he had setup firebase from his account too. Changing package name and creating new project solved the issue